# can not uninstall microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable x86 9.0.21022

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

Actually I started my machine early in the morning and microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable x86 9.0.21022 is installed on my machine by some program and now half of applications fails to run on my machine. When I try to run any applications I got following error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000000c)"

I suppose incorrect version - x86(32 bit) of Microsoft visual c++ installed on my 64 bit version that might cause this issue. Now I am trying to remove it from "Programs and Features" but I got error "Windows installed stopped working". I am stuck to this problem during last 15 days. Has anyone any idea about this ?

My Machine Details
OS : Windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: I am not able to understand what's wrong with my question. Why downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to find out concrete solution for it but i resolve this issue by running following command on command prompt

```
sfc /scannow
```

but every time i restart my machine this issue will reappear.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is old, but I've also tried to uninstall **Visual C++ Redistributable** (this and newer versions), but no luck. For me it said that it cannot find the program. **The fix** that worked in windows 10 was to not use Add or Remove programs, instead I've used Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features and from here I've clicked Uninstall. This could see that the actual programs were uninstalled and removed them from the list. This allowed me to install the newer version.
I just wanted to post this because it took me a few days until I found the solution by mistake.